# How to configure Spring MVC (spring boot) with authorization that is deny by default allow by annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I would like my Spring-HATEOAS API application (built on Spring-Boot and Spring-MVC) to have security configured such that all endpoints/controller methods are deny by default and can only have access explicitly granted by method annotations.

I have been able to get it so annotations control all access, but if a developer forgets to add an annotation the method is accessible to anonymous users.  I would like it such that the developer must explicitly annotate (or do some other explicit development action) the method in order to allow anonymous access.

Maybe i need to write a custom AccessDecisionManager, but i think it's reasonable to suspect that deny by default behaviour is baked in...i just have to turn the right knob.

I've been trying in vain to do this with something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http        
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .hasRole("NOONEHASIT")
        ;
    }
}
```

and a controller like:

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('DEFAULT') or isAnonymous()")
    public HttpEntity<RootResource> root(){
        //stuff
    }
}
```

with the idea that nobody has that role, but this just denies everybody.

anyone got the magic sauce?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think if a way to do that without explicitly allowing the paths that you want to annotate as well. So you need another filter chain (ie another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) with lower `Order` that explicitly allows access to all the paths you need to protect. You might be able to automate that, e.g. look for `@RequestMappings` with `@PreAuthorize`, but it will be fiddly, and I'm not sure it's worth it.

N.B. I don't think you need a non-existent role in your catch-all filter: you can just `denyAll()`.

Comment: there's no way to make a accessdecissionmanager that just defaults to deny?  Using the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as i have in my example is not a necessity..it was just he path i was going

Comment: oh, i think i'm getting it now.  The http security does not take into account the annotations at all...that check is done much later down the pipeline via the MethodInvocation stuff.  So you have to allow the attempt to even get to the MethodInvocation stuff.

Comment: Yes, that's it in a nutshell. The HTTP security is a filter applied *before* any method security is evaluated, so there' no point denying all at that level.

Comment: Anyway to get methodinvocation to deny by default controller methods (seems unlikely)

Comment: You probably could do something with `@RequestMapping` methods, using them to define a pointcut in the absence of `@PreAuthorize`. Like I said, fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deny-access:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) 
public class DenyMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return new CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
    }
    ...
}
```

```
public class CustomPermissionAllowedMethodSecurityMetadataSource 
  extends AbstractFallbackMethodSecurityMetadataSource {
    @Override
    protected Collection findAttributes(Class<?> clazz) { return null; }

    @Override
    protected Collection findAttributes(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
        Annotation[] annotations = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotations(method);
        List attributes = new ArrayList<>();

        // if the class is annotated as @Controller we should by default deny access to all methods
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(targetClass, Controller.class) != null) {
            attributes.add(DENY_ALL_ATTRIBUTE);
        }

        if (annotations != null) {
            for (Annotation a : annotations) {
                // but not if the method has at least a PreAuthorize or PostAuthorize annotation
                if (a instanceof PreAuthorize || a instanceof PostAuthorize) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection getAllConfigAttributes() { return null; }
}
```